# Is there a guaranteed execution order of rerender and oncomplete

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I am trying with actionFunction's rerender and oncomplete. During my testing, it seems to me that rerender happens before the execution oncomplete method. But is that a guaranteed thing? I don't see that in any existing doc though

Comment: In my experience it always happens in that order...

Comment: I have always expected `oncomplete` to run last and it always has for me. I expect `oncomplete` to run on complete, so "when everything else is completed".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The order of operations with an ajax request is:

1. `onClick`/`onSubmit` functions are called
2. ajax form POST to controller
3. (wait patiently while controller does work)
4. response received from Salesforce
5. `onBeforeDomUpdate` is called
6. DOM is updated (using the collection of rerender element names)
7. `onComplete` is called
8. page is ready for the user again

I can't find any Salesforce docs that describe this order, but there may be some reference material available within the [JBoss RichFaces framework](http://richfaces.jboss.org/).

.